# Objective-C iOS, set a delay for an update of text

Tags: objective-c, ios, timer

I'm trying to find a solution to a problem I just stumbled upon. 
Tried to search for it but it's not that I'm looking for.

I'm doing a GPS-app with two tabbars. I track the distance in the map-view (using CLLocation) and when I change tab to a different view the stringtext that say what distance it is from when I started don't update immediately, it take a couple of seconds.

And when I press the stop button I want it to either wait those couple of seconds so the real distance updates. But I dont want to freeze the app. 
(*NSDate *future = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 3.0 ];
[NSThread sleepUntilDate:future];*)

I'm saving the string with the distance in a cell in the second tab, so if I multitask while the app is going I want to just start the app and press stop. And then the new distance will be correct and saved. Hope I didn't confuse you with this much text I hope you understand what I asking for!

thx

Comment: How'bout firing up developer.apple.com and reading the docs?

Answer (score 2):

```
[label performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:newText afterDelay:3.0];
```

Comment: Here's [manual reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-performSelector_withObject_afterDelay_) for `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`

Comment: [myLabel performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:theString afterDelay:3.0f];

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is use dispatch_after:

```
dispatch_after(3 seconds, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        myLabel.text = <the value you want to appear>;
    } );
```